# What are the techniques for initializing a network of objects which need to communicate with each other?

Tags: rust

I have a bunch of objects that implement some traits. For each object, I need to inject a vector of traits, which are listeners.

The problem I run into is that I need the objects to be both reference counted and mutable during initialization. Here's the construction:

```
impl Game {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let bg = Rc::new(Background::new());
        let time_counter = Rc::new(TimeCounter::new());
        let flag_counter = Rc::new(FlagCounter::new());
        let game_state_button = Rc::new(GameStateButton::new());
        let grid = Rc::new(Grid::new());

        let object_listeners: Vec<Weak<dyn ObjectListener>> = vec![
            Rc::downgrade(&game_state_button) as Weak<dyn ObjectListener>,
            Rc::downgrade(&flag_counter) as Weak<dyn ObjectListener>,
        ];
        grid.assign_object_listeners(object_listeners);

        let game_state_listeners: Vec<Weak<dyn GameStateListener>> = vec![
            Rc::downgrade(&time_counter) as Weak<dyn GameStateListener>,
            Rc::downgrade(&flag_counter) as Weak<dyn GameStateListener>,
            Rc::downgrade(&grid) as Weak<dyn GameStateListener>,
        ];
        game_state_button.assign_game_state_listeners(game_state_listeners);

        let flag_state_listeners: Vec<Weak<dyn FlagStateListener>> = vec![
            Rc::downgrade(&grid) as Weak<dyn FlagStateListener>,
        ];
        flag_counter.assign_flag_state_listeners(flag_state_listeners);

        let sprites: Vec<Rc<dyn Sprite>> = vec![
            Rc::clone(&bg) as Rc<dyn Sprite>,
            Rc::clone(&time_counter) as Rc<dyn Sprite>,
            Rc::clone(&flag_counter) as Rc<dyn Sprite>,
            Rc::clone(&game_state_button) as Rc<dyn Sprite>,
            Rc::clone(&grid) as Rc<dyn Sprite>,
        ];
        Game { sprites }
    }
}
```

The assignments will mutate the object, causing a problem for `Rc`. I could use `RefCell`, which works, but feels wrong. I've looked at `channel`, and I could create a bunch of channels and then inject them during object construction (either the send or receive), but that feels wrong as well. I've looked at [specs](https://docs.rs/specs/0.16.1/specs/index.html) and am still digesting it.

Can anyone suggest a better organization which encodes a graph of communication between objects? As a last resort, I could stuff the listeners into the `Game` object and inject a reference counted game object into each object, however, that feels twisted.

Here's how I solved lots of issues. I realized I had a communication graph, which the objects use. I constructed a helper to ease the wiring of channels to objects. I then construct the graph, and inject it into the objects during construction. This also cleaned up ownership, as Rc is no longer needed. Here's the code now:

```
pub fn new(layout: Layout) -> Game {
    // get all the channel wiring setup
    let mut channels = ChannelWiring::default();
    channels.wire::<Grid, Button>();
    channels.wire::<Grid, FlagCounter>();

    channels.wire::<Button, TimeCounter>();
    channels.wire::<Button, FlagCounter>();
    channels.wire::<Button, Grid>();

    channels.wire::<FlagCounter, Grid>();

    let mut sprites: Vec<Box<dyn Sprite>> = Vec::new();

    // create the underlying objects, and own via trait
    sprites.push(Box::new(Background {}));
    sprites.push(Box::new(TimeCounter::new(&mut channels)));
    sprites.push(Box::new(FlagCounter::new(layout, &mut channels)));
    sprites.push(Box::new(Button::new(layout, &mut channels)));
    sprites.push(Box::new(Grid::new(layout, &mut channels)));

    // finally create the game object
    Game { sprites: sprites }
}
```

With reference counting going away, so too did the need for RefCell.

Comment: *[RefCell] feels wrong* — why? *[a channel] feels wrong* — why? *that feels twisted* — perhaps that's an artifact of the problem space, not the language. Your `Rc` / `Weak` / `RefCell` is effectively a simple garbage collector.

Comment: RefCell feels wrong, at least to me, as I never mutate the listeners once constructed. In the back of my mind, I'm feeling like I'm forcing things and RefCell is what I'm using to get around it.